# Aligning Two Controls, one of which uses all available space - Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Pretty simple problem but I just can't seem to configure this correctly.

I would a ListVieww aligned right taking up 100dp of layout_width, whilst a MapControl takes up the remaining space. (I'd rather it take up remaining space to take advantage of the phone being put in a horizontal position.

Here's what I have at the moment.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


             <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="left" >


                 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                 android:id="@+id/gmap"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:clickable="true"
                 android:layout_gravity="left"
                 />
                 </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/maplst"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" > 

        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        style="@style/listViewStyle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="right">
    </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>  


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need all these layouts (optimization point). To take the remaining space, use `layout_width="0dp"` with a `layout_weight="1"`.

This should be want you want:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                 android:id="@+id/gmap"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:clickable="true"
                 />

      <ListView
             android:id="@+id/listView1"
             android:layout_width="100dp"
             style="@style/listViewStyle"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code where listview is aligned left of screen occupying 100dp space and rest occupied by the mapview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/maplst"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/maplst">

        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/gmap"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:clickable="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```